# Features with geomety issues or unexpected CRS in Geopackage tables

Tags: coordinate-system, geopackage, null-geometry

In my project I've been asked to make some data validations to GeoPackage tables previous to start processing the data. I'm doing this with FME Dekstop.

Among other properties I should validate that features in each table have the expected coordinate system and geometry type. I have some experience working with shapefiles and I've come across features with null geometry and other geometry problems or a different coordinate system than the rest of features, but I have few experience working with GeoPackage and don't know whether this same issues may occur with GeoPackage tables.
If that's not possible it would simplify the validation and reporting/logging process. Assuming all features have same properties I would just check the defined geometry type and coordinate system for the table.

Using QGIS I've been trying to create features in a GeoPackage table with different properties that the rest to no avail and I can't find an example or issue anyone may have had with that. So I need your experience to reply to this question and/or give me some tips to intentionally generating incorrect features in a GeoPackage table using QGIS.

Comment: If you manage to do that with QGIS or GDAL you have found a bug. A set of triggers are trying to safeguard the database. I would recommend to create a valid GeoPackage with QGIS or GDAL and use generic SQLite tools for disabling triggers and constraints, and for manipulating data.

Comment: @user30184 I understand then that it's very unlikely that any of the commented issues happen, unless data creators make that kind of manipulation to the their GeoPackage.

Comment: It is not very unlikely that software has bugs. It is rather hard to make SRID to not match but some polygon/multipolygon mixtures are not rare even table is registered to contain just one or another. I hope you already know validate_gpkg.py https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/swig/python/samples/validate_gpkg.py and the OGC Team engine https://cite.opengeospatial.org/teamengine/.